# What does $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B(b \in C \rightarrow a \in C)$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

What does $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B(b \in C \rightarrow a \in C)$ mean?

I know it means that for all $a$ in $A$ there exists a $b$ in $B$ such that $b$ in $C$ implies $a$ in $C$, but what does that mean intuitively, because to me the interaction between the $\exists$ and the implication doesn't make any sense.  It seems to be saying that there exists a $b$ in $B$ and if that $b$ happens to be in $C$, then it implies that $A \subseteq C$?  Does it means that the entire set of $A$ is that one element of $B$ and it's also in $C$?

Comment: Do you mean to have $\forall C$ to left of $\forall a\in A$? Without quantifying $C$, the formula you're asking about doesn't mean anything.

Comment: What would $\forall C$ mean?

Comment: Usually we're within $\sf ZFC$ in which everything is a set. So $\forall C$ means for any set $C$. An informal of way of addressing this is: $$\quad$$
Let $C$ be a set. What does $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B(b \in C \rightarrow a \in C)$ mean? (I hope I am not confusing you further). **Edit:** and of course the same has to be said for $A$ and $B$ too.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's understood.  A, B, and C are arbitrary sets.

Comment: I think this is irrelevant. Let's just assume $C$ is some fixed set.

Comment: @GitGud I don't think it's fair to say that all formulas with free variables are meaningless.

Comment: @TrevorWilson With 'meaningless' I mean that they aren't statements.

Comment: @GitGud I gathered that.  But I disagree that, for example, "$p$ is divisible only by itself and 1" is meaningless.  I think it means that $p$ is prime.  I think your definition of meaningful is unusual.

Comment: I don't think it is unusual. I believe it is the very definition of a 'formula with meaning'. It's one thing to interpret from context. When you assume $p$ is prime, you're bounding it with a quantifier.

Comment: @GitGud I'm not _assuming_ that $p$ is prime, nor am I _assuming_ that $p$ is divisible only by itself and 1.  I'm just saying that both of these phrases (technically, formulas) have _meaning_.  Anyway, as far as I'm aware "meaning" is not a mathematical term, so I think we'll have to agree to disagree on what this particular English word means.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $b\in C\to a\in C$ is equivalent to $b\notin C\lor a\in C$. Thus, it says that there is a function $f:A\to B$ with the following property:

> for each $a\in A$, either $f(a)\notin C$, or $a\in C$.

If $A\subseteq C$, this is guaranteed to be the case provided that $B\ne\varnothing$: we can pick any $b_0\in B$ and let $f(a)=b_0$ for each $a\in A$.

If $A\nsubseteq C$, fix $a_0\in A\setminus C$. In order for the highlighted statement to be true, we must be able to define $f(a_0)\in B$ in such a way that $f(a_0)\notin C$, which means that $B\setminus C$ must be non-empty. Conversely, if there is a $b_0\in B\setminus C$, we may let $f(a)=b_0$ for all $a\in A$, and this $f$ will have the desired property.

All of this boils down to saying that the statement is true if and only if $B\ne\varnothing$, and either $A\subseteq C$ or $B\nsubseteq C$.

Comment: In your last sentence you seem to have lost the "provided $B\neq \varnothing$" for the $A\subseteq C$ case.

Comment: @Henning: So I did; thanks. (And it comes for free with the other case, so I might as well just make it an independent conjunct).

Comment: Wow, you blew my mind when you said it says there's a function.  I need a minute to mull that over.

Comment: @Matt: That’s just putting $\forall a\in A\exists b\in B$ into what may be more familiar terms. For each $a\in A$ there is some $b\in B$ with a certain property; I could call it $b_a$ to specify that it’s a chosen $b$ that ‘works’ for that $a$, but I chose instead to call it $f(a)$.

Comment: But actually it's not quite a function because there could be more than one $b$ that qualifies, right?  In other words $\exists$ means there is at least one.

Comment: @Matt: Sure, but I can choose a particular one and call it $b_a$ or $f(a)$. To put it differently, there may be lots of functions $f:A\to B$ that work.

Comment: Oh okay, I see.  I'm getting confused.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Matt: You’re welcome. If you figure out exactly what’s confusing you, I’ll be happy to try to sort it out.

Comment: @Brian: Perhaps his intuition works without Choice, in which case $\forall x\exists y$ _isn't_ automatically the same as the existence of a function that maps $x$s to $y$s?

Comment: @Henning: Despite a modest amount of evidence to the contrary, I actually find it a bit hard to believe that anyone’s native intuition works without Choice. (I deliberately chose not to worry about it, because I thought that the function idea was a good answer to the request for an intuitive meaning.)

Answer (score 3):

It is probably easiest to understand this by using the rule that $P\to Q$ means the same as $\neg P\lor Q$. So what we have here is

$$ \forall a\in A. \exists b \in B. (b\notin C \lor a \in C)$$

Now, let's consider the subformula $\exists b \in B. (b\notin C \lor a \in C)$. It should be clear that if there is a $b$ such that $b\notin C$, then this is true no matter what $a$ is. On the other hand, if $a\in C$, then it is true if only $B$ contains *some* $b$. So this is equivalent to $(\exists b\in B. b\notin C) \lor (B\neq \varnothing \land a \in C)$. So we have

$\forall a \in A. \bigl( (\exists b\in B. b\notin C) \lor (B\neq \varnothing \land a \in C)\bigr)$

Now again this is certainly true if $\exists b\in B. b\notin C$ is. Otherwise we must have $B\neq\varnothing$ and $a\in C$ for all $a\in A$. So it is equivalent to

$$(\exists b\in B. b\notin C) \lor (B \neq \varnothing \land \forall a\in A. a\in C)$$

We can rewrite that to use set algebra instead of logic, so see that what the original formula "really" means is

$$ B\setminus C \neq \varnothing \lor (B \neq \varnothing \land A\subseteq C)$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is more illuminating to look at it written in the following form:

$$\forall_{a\in A}\left(\exists_{b\in B}\left(b\in C\implies a\in C\right)\right)$$

In this way, you can think of $\forall_{a\in A}$ as an operator acting on the stuff in the brackets. Like all other boolean operators, it will return truth or falsehood. A similar analogy holds for $\exists_{b\in B}$. Consider the following:

$$\forall_{a\in A}\left(p\left(a\right)\right)$$

Here, $p\colon A \rightarrow \left\{0,1\right\}$ is just a proposition: it maps elements of $A$ to true ($1$) or false ($0$). Concretely, if we assume as a means to an example that $A=\left\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right\}$, we would have

$$\forall_{a\in A}\left(p\left(a\right)\right) = p\left(a_1\right) \wedge p\left(a_2\right) \wedge \ldots \wedge p\left(a_n\right)$$

where $\wedge$ is the **and** operator. Hope that helps.

All this having been said, the subscript notation is used almost nowhere, although it has the advantage of being unambiguous.

**Edit**: Here is an example with existence assuming $A$ is finite as before:

$$\exists_{a\in A}\left(p\left(a\right)\right) = p\left(a_1\right) \vee p\left(a_2\right) \vee \ldots \vee p\left(a_n\right)$$

where $\vee$ is the **or** operator.

**Relation to your original problem**: This doesn't imply that $A\subseteq C$. For example, take $A=\left\{a\right\}$ and $B = \left\{b\right\}$ and $ C = \emptyset$. Then, clearly, the proposition is satisfied trivially, but $A$ is not a subset of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

> What does $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B(b \in C \rightarrow a \in C)$ mean?
>
> I know it means that for all $a$ in $A$ there exists a $b$ in $B$ such that $b$ in $C$ implies $a$ in $C$, but what does that mean intuitively, because to me the interaction between the $\exists$ and the implication doesn't make any sense.  It seems to be saying that there exists a $b$ in $B$ and if that $b$ happens to be in $C$, then it implies that $A \subseteq C$?  Does it means that the entire set of $A$ is that one element of $B$ and it's also in $C$?

There is no suggestion here that $A \subseteq C$, or equivalently that $\forall a( a\in A\rightarrow a\in C)$.

Suppose $p\in A$. Then it follows that

$\exists b\in B(b\in C \rightarrow p\in C)$

or equivalently

$\exists b (b\in B\land(b\notin C \lor p\in C))$.

It does not necessarily follow that $p\in C$.